# ng-repeat angular adding two elements to a div as opposed to one when iterating through array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using angular to make a get request to return live data. I then wish to display this data on my home page.

The code in my controller is as follows:

```
$scope.holder = [];

  $http.get('url').success(function(data){
      $scope.lines = data.lines;
       $.each($scope.lines, function(name){
        $scope.holder.push(this.friendly_name);
        $scope.holder.push(this.status);
      });
  });
});
```

The $scope.holder array looks like this after the data has been called:

["Bakerloo", "Good service", "Central", "Part closure", "Circle", "Good service", "District", "Part closure", "Hammersmith & City", "Good service"]

My html looks like this:

```
<body ng-controller="tubeController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in holder track by $index">
      {{item}}
    </div>
</body>
```

When I display this on the html page each element of the array is put into a separate div which looks like this:

```
<div>Bakerloo</div>
<div>Good Service</div>
<div>Central</div>
<div>Part closure</div>
```

What I want to do is bunch the elements by two so that each div has two elements from the array included.

I want the page to look like this:

```
<div>Bakerloo Good service</div>
<div>Central Part closure</div>
```

etc.

I have tried many different techniques, and read many other answers on stack overflow but cannot get it. I am hoping someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each($scope.lines, function(name){
    $scope.holder.push( this.friendly_name + " " + this.status );
});
```

Comment: worked an absolute charm, cant believe I didnt spot it, but thank you, really nice solution. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. Thanks again